# How to replace "fetch" with "ajax" method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, api

I'm trying to wrap my head around ajax now that this is using fetch to retreive the data. 
The syntax is the same roughly, but was curious as to what it would look like.

---

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="searchContainer">
        <input class="searchControl" type="text" placeholder="City Name or Zipcode" id="searchInput">
        <button class="searchControl" id="searchBtn">Search</button>
    </div>
    <div id="weatherContainer">
        <div id="weatherDescription">
            <h1 id="cityHeader"></h1>
            <div id="weatherMain">
                <div id="temperature"></div>
                <div id="weatherDescriptionHeader"></div>
                <div><img id="documentIconImg"></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div id="windSpeed" class="bottom-details"></div>
            <div id="humidity" class="bottom-details"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js" ></script>
</body>
```

Here is the JavaScript I'd like to convert from using the fetch method, to using an AJAX call in place of it.

```
---
let appId = 'b1e22f9b3891a9a6fc389e3e1a4cc496';
let units = 'imperial'; 
let searchMethod; 

function getSearchMethod(searchTerm) {
    if(searchTerm.length === 5 && Number.parseInt(searchTerm) + '' === searchTerm)
        searchMethod = 'zip';
    else 
        searchMethod = 'q';
}

function searchWeather(searchTerm) {
    getSearchMethod(searchTerm);
    fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?${searchMethod}=${searchTerm}&APPID=${appId}&units=${units}`)
        .then((result) => {
            return result.json();
        }).then((res) => {
            init(res);
    });
}

function init(resultFromServer) {
    switch (resultFromServer.weather[0].main) {
        case 'Clear':
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('clear.jpg')";
            break;

        case 'Clouds':
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('cloudy.jpg')";
            break;

        case 'Rain':
        case 'Drizzle':
        case 'Mist':
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('rain.jpg')";
            break;

        case 'Thunderstorm':
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('storm.jpg')";
            break;

        case 'Snow':
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('snow.jpg')";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    let weatherDescriptionHeader = document.getElementById('weatherDescriptionHeader');
    let temperatureElement = document.getElementById('temperature');
    let humidityElement = document.getElementById('humidity');
    let windSpeedElement = document.getElementById('windSpeed');
    let cityHeader = document.getElementById('cityHeader');

    let weatherIcon = document.getElementById('documentIconImg');
    weatherIcon.src = 'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + resultFromServer.weather[0].icon + '.png';

    let resultDescription = resultFromServer.weather[0].description;
    weatherDescriptionHeader.innerText = resultDescription.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + resultDescription.slice(1);
    temperatureElement.innerHTML = Math.floor(resultFromServer.main.temp) + '&#176;';
    windSpeedElement.innerHTML = 'Winds at  ' + Math.floor(resultFromServer.wind.speed) + ' m/s';
    cityHeader.innerHTML = resultFromServer.name;
    humidityElement.innerHTML = 'Humidity levels at ' + resultFromServer.main.humidity +  '%';

    setPositionForWeatherInfo();
}

function setPositionForWeatherInfo() {
    let weatherContainer = document.getElementById('weatherContainer');
    let weatherContainerHeight = weatherContainer.clientHeight;
    let weatherContainerWidth = weatherContainer.clientWidth;

    weatherContainer.style.left = `calc(50% - ${weatherContainerWidth/2}px)`;
    weatherContainer.style.top = `calc(50% - ${weatherContainerHeight/1.3}px)`;
    weatherContainer.style.visibility = 'visible';
}

document.getElementById('searchBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    let searchTerm = document.getElementById('searchInput').value;
    if(searchTerm)
        searchWeather(searchTerm);
});
---
```

If anyone has any ideas or knows a solution that 100% works feel free to share. Not sure what to do.

Comment: What you are looking for is called **polyfill**. See this one : https://github.com/github/fetch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** is this answer wrong or something?? Not sure why the downvotes?? Sheesh.....

`fetch` and `$.ajax` are different routes to the same destination. They both *loosely* behave like [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)..

I would recommend sticking with `fetch` since is is widely supported ***by default***, is easier to use than `XMLHttpRequest`, and does not require any third party libraries. To use `$.ajax`, (as far as I am aware) you have to import `jQuery` - which imports a lot of unnecessary code along with `$.ajax`. If you can do things without a third party library, you should.

With that being said, using `$.ajax` would look something like this:

***SPECIFIC FUNCTION:***

```
function searchWeather(searchTerm) {
  getSearchMethod(searchTerm);
  $.ajax({
    url: `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?${searchMethod}=${searchTerm}&APPID=${appId}&units=${units}`,
    success: (data) => {
      init(data);
    },
    failure: (err) => {
      console.log("ERROR!", err);
    }
  });
}
```

***DEMO:***

```js
let appId = "b1e22f9b3891a9a6fc389e3e1a4cc496";
let units = "imperial";
let searchMethod;

function getSearchMethod(searchTerm) {
  if (searchTerm.length === 5 && Number.parseInt(searchTerm) + "" === searchTerm)
    searchMethod = "zip";
  else searchMethod = "q";
}

function searchWeather(searchTerm) {
  getSearchMethod(searchTerm);
  $.ajax({
    url: `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?${searchMethod}=${searchTerm}&APPID=${appId}&units=${units}`,
    success: (data) => {
      init(data);
    },
    failure: (err) => {
      console.log("ERROR!", err);
    }
  })
    /*
    fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?${searchMethod}=${searchTerm}&APPID=${appId}&units=${units}`)
    .then(result => {
      return result.json();
    })
    .then(res => {
      init(res);
    });
    */
}

function init(resultFromServer) {
  switch (resultFromServer.weather[0].main) {
    case "Clear":
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('clear.jpg')";
      break;

    case "Clouds":
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('cloudy.jpg')";
      break;

    case "Rain":
    case "Drizzle":
    case "Mist":
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('rain.jpg')";
      break;

    case "Thunderstorm":
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('storm.jpg')";
      break;

    case "Snow":
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('snow.jpg')";
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }

  let weatherDescriptionHeader = document.getElementById(
    "weatherDescriptionHeader"
  );
  let temperatureElement = document.getElementById("temperature");
  let humidityElement = document.getElementById("humidity");
  let windSpeedElement = document.getElementById("windSpeed");
  let cityHeader = document.getElementById("cityHeader");

  let weatherIcon = document.getElementById("documentIconImg");
  weatherIcon.src =
    "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" +
    resultFromServer.weather[0].icon +
    ".png";

  let resultDescription = resultFromServer.weather[0].description;
  weatherDescriptionHeader.innerText =
    resultDescription.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + resultDescription.slice(1);
  temperatureElement.innerHTML =
    Math.floor(resultFromServer.main.temp) + "&#176;";
  windSpeedElement.innerHTML =
    "Winds at  " + Math.floor(resultFromServer.wind.speed) + " m/s";
  cityHeader.innerHTML = resultFromServer.name;
  humidityElement.innerHTML =
    "Humidity levels at " + resultFromServer.main.humidity + "%";

  setPositionForWeatherInfo();
}

function setPositionForWeatherInfo() {
  let weatherContainer = document.getElementById("weatherContainer");
  let weatherContainerHeight = weatherContainer.clientHeight;
  let weatherContainerWidth = weatherContainer.clientWidth;

  weatherContainer.style.left = `calc(50% - ${weatherContainerWidth / 2}px)`;
  weatherContainer.style.top = `calc(50% - ${weatherContainerHeight / 1.3}px)`;
  weatherContainer.style.visibility = "visible";
}

document.getElementById("searchBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let searchTerm = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
  if (searchTerm) searchWeather(searchTerm);
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="searchContainer">
    <input class="searchControl" type="text" placeholder="City Name or Zipcode" id="searchInput">
    <button class="searchControl" id="searchBtn">Search</button>
  </div>
  <div id="weatherContainer">
    <div id="weatherDescription">
      <h1 id="cityHeader"></h1>
      <div id="weatherMain">
        <div id="temperature"></div>
        <div id="weatherDescriptionHeader"></div>
        <div><img id="documentIconImg"></div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div id="windSpeed" class="bottom-details"></div>
      <div id="humidity" class="bottom-details"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```